# My switcher demo code is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, switch-statement

In my project I have 4 modes and 4 steps for users and users have to choose in which step he/she is going to use which mode. It's totally depending on the user.
For that application the switch case concept is correct, right?
Please suggest a way guys, as I am new to python. I am in a big dilemma.
I created some demo code, which isn't working either.

```
def mode1():
    print( "hi")
def mode2():
    print('hello')
def mode3():
    print("good")
def mode4():
    print("like")
def step_demo(arg):
    switcher={
       '1':mode1,
        '2':mode2,
        '3':mode3,
        '4':mode4,
    }
    return switcher.get(arg,"nothing")
if __name__=="__main__":
    arg=str(input("enter choice: "))
    step_demo(arg)
```

What is wrong with this code?
It is not giving any output.

Comment: `print(step_demo(arg))` ?

Comment: @Rakesh,i tried this also but gives me `enter choice: 1
<function mode1 at 0x0000013AE260B8B0>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the function itself, without executing it.
Try it like this:

```
def mode1():
    return 'hi'
def mode2():
    return 'hello'
def mode3():
    return 'good'
def mode4():
    return 'like'

def step_demo(arg):
    switcher={
        '1': mode1,
        '2': mode2,
        '3': mode3,
        '4': mode4,
    }
    # First get the function from the switcher
    func = switcher.get(arg, lambda: "nothing")
    # Execute it
    return func()

if __name__=="__main__":
    arg=str(input("enter choice: "))
    print(step_demo(arg))
```

Changed the prints to returns and only print the returned value.

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion